# Spatial data methods in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to use distance as a parameter in a c# linq query. The following where clause returns an error of "STGeomFromText doesn't exist in this context":

```
query = from i in _db.ILV
    join p in _db.PC on
    i.PostCode equals p.PostCode
    where (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(rng)) ? STGeomFromText(i.Point).STDistance(q.Point) <= rng : true
```

using System.Spatial has been declared. Can anyone show me the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are in a data context.  In that case, you should be using System.Data.Spatial and you won't be able to call that function directly.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859721.aspx

For additional information on using spatial geometries with entities, see 
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2011/05/04/spatial-types-in-the-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: The problem I keep running into is when I try to declare using System.Data.Spatial, the system tells me it doesn't exist.

Comment: You need to include it as a reference then in your project.  Right click project -> add references -> search for the reference.

Comment: System.Data.Spatial doesn't show up as an option in references.

Comment: I've deleted my answer because @DavidL's is precise. You can't call external linq methods inside linq queries, the reason is simple: don't have SQL-equivalent. It appears there is a workaround for your scenario and DavidL pointed it.

Comment: @user3380512 It is part of the .NET framework.  Are you searching under assemblies?

Comment: Found it. It's now System.Data.Entity.Spatial in Entity Framework 6.0. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This is now possible in memory or using EF Core 2.2 using the Nuget package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer.NetTopologySuite

```
using NetTopologySuite.Geometries;
using System.Linq;

var here = new Point(53.791299, -1.547772) { SRID = 104001 };
var places = Data.Places.Where(p => p.Location.Distance(here) < 100);
```

See [EF Core 2.2 Release](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.2) notes for more info.